# Determining if a Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition is refering to the same function as a given EnvDTE.CodeFunction

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, envdte, mono.cecil

#### Context

I've been trying out jbEvain's powerful Mono.Cecil library for just about two weeks now. I've created the following function :

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns true only if they match. 
/// </summary>
private bool CompareMethodDefinitionWithCodeFunction(
                EnvDTE.CodeFunction pCodeFunction,
                Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition pMethodDefintion)
{
    return pMethodDefintion.Name.Equals(pCodeFunction.Name) 
        && pMethodDefintion.Parameters.Count == pCodeFunction.Parameters.Count;
}
```

#### Goal

The goal is to determine whether `pCodeFunction` and `pMethodDefinition` are refering to the same function definition or not. So far, I am able to compare the functions' names and the number of parameters they have. I am well aware that it's not enough to certify that they really are refering to the same function. I need help on improving my comparison. For instance, I believe one should always compare the parameter types in order to take potential function overrides into account.

#### Previous attempts

I have tried comparing the parameter types but none of my attempts prevailed. Allow me to demonstrate.

I thought I could compare the types as strings so I added abit of code like so :

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns true only if they match. 
/// </summary>
private bool CompareMethodDefinitionWithCodeFunction(
                EnvDTE.CodeFunction pCodeFunction,
                Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition pMethodDefintion)
{

    foreach (ParameterDefinition paramDef in pMethodDefintion.Parameters)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(paramDef.ParameterType.FullName);
    }

    foreach (CodeElement ce in pCodeFunction.Parameters)
    {
        CodeParameter codeParameter = ce as CodeParameter;
        Debug.WriteLine(codeParameter.Type.AsFullName);
    }
    return pMethodDefintion.Name.Equals(pCodeFunction.Name) 
        && pMethodDefintion.Parameters.Count == pCodeFunction.Parameters.Count;
}
```

Given that `pCodeFunction` was refering to the following VB.Net function at runtime

```
Public Function SomeFunction(ByVal arg As List(Of String)) As Object
    Return New Object()
End Function
```

I got the following output

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.String>
System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.String)
```

I would prefer not to mess around with these two output values and try to parse them so that they match because this doesn't seem like a very "reliable" way to compare types. What is be the most reliable way to compare the parameter types?

#### Bonus Notes

This function must be able to seek a function's definition so long as the source code is either VB or C#.

I am currently using the latest Mono.Cecil build (3.12.1) which you can download [here](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win)

If you want to use my function and insert it in a test class that you've made, you will need the following imports :

```
using EnvDTE;
using Mono.Cecil;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, after a few more attemps at comparing them appropriately, that there aren't any "proper" ways available out there to compare these two types of objects.

But, I have found a different solution that implies calculating a function index relative to every other function defined within the class. It can get a tiny bit complicated when we start taking the constructors defined in the IL code in consideration but I still think it's appropriate to post this answer  out here since it has been my final solution so far. And to be quite frank, the solution as a whole is quite simple.

Allow me to lay out a simple class for demonstrative purposes :

```
class Class1
{
    public static void Function1(string arg1, string arg2) 
    {
        //business logic
    }

    public static Object Function2(Object arg1) 
    {
        //business logic
    }

    public static void Function2(List<string> arg1) 
    {
        //business logic
    }
}
```

#### Function Index

What is my function index supposed to be? Using my Class1 example, simply put, the function's corresponding indexes would be :

- 0
- 1
- 2

Of course, the said function index isn't some property that comes with EnvDTE. I will have to calculate it myself. To implement it, I created a class that contains a `EnvDTE.CodeFunction` property as well as an `int` property (intended for the function index).

```
public class CodeFunctionWithIndex
{
    public CodeFunction CodeFunction { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

As for our `Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition`'s function indexes, since we are looping on them (see main post), we can easily calculate their indexes.

It doesn't simply end here though! There are a few things that I need to mention if you want to use the same approach.

To my limited understanding of what goes on behind Mono.Cecil's convenient library, the list of `MethodDefinition` we are looping through contains all the functions that were generated in IL code after our dll was compiled. But, the class from which our `EnvDTE.CodeFunctions` reside isn't compiled.

#### Does a `Mono.Cecil.Type` (AKA class) contain as many functions as a `EnvDTE.ProjectItem` (refering to the class)?

No!
Here is what we will have to consider : the constructor(s). A class may or may not have explicitly defined constuctors. But, a `Mono.Cecil.Type` (AKA the class object of `Mono.Cecil`) **must contain at least one constructor**. And believe me, if you don't explicitly define your own constructor, there will be one in the `Mono.Cecil.Type`!

Finding out if a constructor is explicitly defined within our `EnvDTE.ProjectItem`(refering to the class) isn't such a hard task. Well... unless you consider the following code complicated.

```
private List<CodeFunctionWithIndex> GetExplicitlyDefinedConstructors(vsCMElement pRequestedCodeElementKind, CodeElements pCodeElements)
{
    int nbCodeFunction = 0; //calculated function index
    List<CodeFunctionWithIndex> constructorList = new List<CodeFunctionWithIndex>();
    if (pCodeElements != null)
    {
        foreach (CodeElement element in pCodeElements)
        {
            //if current element is a namespace
            if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace)
            {
                constructorList = GetExplicitlyDefinedConstructors(pRequestedCodeElementKind, ((EnvDTE.CodeNamespace)element).Members);
                if (!constructorList.Any())
                    continue;
                return constructorList;
            }
            //if current element is a class
            else if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass)
            {
                nbCodeFunction = 0;
                constructorList = GetExplicitlyDefinedConstructors(pRequestedCodeElementKind, ((EnvDTE.CodeClass)element).Members);
                if (!constructorList.Any()) //because there might be more than one class defined within the active file
                    continue;
                return constructorList;
            }
            //if current element's kind equals the requested kind
            else if (element.Kind == pRequestedCodeElementKind)
            {
                nbCodeFunction++;
                //if it's a constructor, add its index to the list of constructor indexes
                if (((CodeFunction)element).FunctionKind.ToString().Contains(vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionConstructor.ToString()))
                {
                    constructorList.Add(
                        new CodeFunctionWithIndex()
                        {
                            CodeFunction = ((CodeFunction)element),
                            Index = nbCodeFunction
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return constructorList;
}
```

And here is how I am calling this function to find out if I have any explicitly defined constructors :

```
GetExplicitlyDefinedConstructors(
        vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction, 
        DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElements)
    .Any();
```

But, if there aren't any constructors defined in it, how can our `Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition`'s function index match with our `EnvDTE.CodeFunction`'s function index?.

Here is the big idea of my solution (tested) :

1. In VB.Net, if there is no explicitly defined constructor within the class, the constructor in the IL code will be situated at the beguining of the class (function index 0).
2. In C#.Net, if there is no explicitly defined constructor within the class, the constructor in the IL code will be situated at the **end** of the class (last function index).

Here is what my function `CompareMethodDefinitionWithCodeFunction` proposed in my first post looks like today (yes it's been renamed... I apologize for that):

```
public MethodDefinition FindMethodDefinition(CodeFunctionWithIndex pCodeFunction, bool pHasAnExplicitlyDefinedCtor)
{
    //Get the assembly that should contain the function we seek
    //Note : this is done by comparing pCodeFunction's assembly name to every assembly's name (without the extension)
    ModuleDefinition assemblyContainingMethod = assemblies
        .Where(assem =>
            assem.Name.Split(new char[] { '.' }).FirstOrDefault()
            .Equals(pCodeFunction.CodeFunction.ProjectItem.ContainingProject.Properties.Item("AssemblyName").Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    //Get the class that should contain the function we seek
    //Note : pCodeFunction.Parent.Name is the class name of our pCodeFunction
    TypeDefinition classContainingMethod =
        assemblyContainingMethod.Types
            .Where(cl => cl.Name.Equals(((CodeClass)pCodeFunction.CodeFunction.Parent).Name))
            .FirstOrDefault();

    //below is what you want to see
    bool isCtorAtIndexZero = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.Name.EndsWith(".vb");
    int functionIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < classContainingMethod.Methods.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!pHasAnExplicitlyDefinedCtor && isCtorAtIndexZero && i == 0)
            continue;
        if (functionIndex == pCodeFunction.Index)
            return classContainingMethod.Methods[i];
        functionIndex++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This code is extracted from a working project.

The `assemblies` variable is a class property of type `List<ModuleDefinition>`. By the time this function is called, it will contain the assembly in which the function we seek can be found.

Bear with me as I can only clarify so much. The project is rather big, in my opinion anyways, and it can perform many operations that I need to omit from this post as it is not directly related to the question in the first place.

Hope this helps at least a tiny bit. I apologize for the wall of text.